# Quero importar uma pagina inteira com jquery, devo dividir a pagina em diferentes jquerys para depois poder escrever codigo pelo meios das jquerys?

Tags: jquery, aspx

Com esta jquery estou a importar a pagina toda, mas nao consigo por html divs no meio da query, só no fim.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Getting Started with jQuery</title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#divteste').load('AdminPagina.aspx')
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div id="divteste">
        <span>Test inside div</span>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
**texto em negrito**</html>
```

Comment: Cara tá bem confusa sua pergunta. Vc quer importar html no topo, no lado esquerdo e no rodapé é isto?

Comment: O import (a preto) eu consegui fazer, através do import de uma outra página (o que quero é a mesma dashboard em todas as páginas), fiz uma jquery onde me importa a página toda. Só que agora eu queria escrever onde está a verde (dentro do import) só que, só consigo escrever por baixo de todo o import, onde está o vermelho. 
Mas sim basicamente o que eu quero fazer é o que vc disse, conseguindo por umas gridviwes onde está o verde , obrigado

Comment: Talvez o melhor seja um framework que faça isso pra você, como o vue.js, por exemplo. Estruturar código baseado em jQuery costuma ficar desorganizado

Comment: Mas aí no caso vc não teria que separar os imports. Fazer um html pro topo, lado e rodapé e assim fazer o import separadamente, deixando o meio livre?

Comment: Guilherme , acho que isto não é tao dificil de fazer assim ao ponto de estar a usar framework ,digo eu. Mas se não tiver outra opção vou experimentar obrigado

Comment: LeAndrade , sim a minha pergunta era mesmo essa , terei eu que dividir os imports para conseguir escrever no meio deles ?

Comment: Dá para vc importar as partes juntas tbm, desde que nesta página vc já deixe um espaço separado no meio que no caso seria o html da página (parte verde) que vai receber o import, entendeu?

Comment: acho que percebi , mas depois na pagina que eu quero, eu chamo a jquery com o import todo junto, já com o espaço verde pronto para por o que quiser , mas e depois como eu ponho la uma div se eu importei tudo junto ? como é que eu escrevo no meio da jquery ? dá para chamar uma div que esteja dentro da jquery ?

Comment: A parte verde vc escreve normalmente, com divs, e tudo mais.

Comment: Se vc reparar no código em cima , eu faço o scrip da jquery e ponho dentro da <div id="divteste"> mas depois eu nao consigo escrever mais nada dentro dessa div , tenho de criar outra e depois essa mesma escreve me por baixo de todo o import (zona vermelha). 
A minha pergunta é o quê que eu chamo para poder escrever na parte verde, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Pedro então como disse, vc já tem que trazer o import com a demarcação certa feita com **html** e **css** *(não sei se está utilizando frameworks como bootstrap)* para posicionar os elementos corretamente. Aí na página que receber estes html já pré-posicionados, vc pode colocar o que quiser dentro do `form` que no seu caso seria a parte verde da sua imagem. Segue o exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#divteste').load('AdminPagina.aspx')
});
```

```css
#form1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="divteste">
     <span>Aqui vai vir importado já -> Topnave - Sidenave - Footer</span>
  </div>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div id="conteudo">
       Aqui vc põe o que vc quiser
     </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Sim estou a usar bootstrap. Nao funcionou, continua a escrever por baixo do import , porque eu estou a importar a pagina toda mesmo com a marcação html direita. O que ele faz é que importa uma div vazia (a área verde), mas nao me deixa escrever o que eu quiser lá. Não sei se estou a fazer alguma coisa mal :/

Comment: Está aparecendo embaixo o form? Tenta colocar o form dentro da div *divteste*.

Comment: Fica por baixo do import (sem se ver)

Comment: Pedro precisaria ver como estão as páginas de import, pq me parece que vc está importando tudo, as tags body tbm, vc teria que montar a página que vai importar apenas com divs, cada uma já posicionada.

Comment: Exacto , eu estou a importar a página toda , com scripts , css, links , bodys , tudo .
Devo então construir a pagina só com divs ? Ou deixo a página criada como está mas importo só as divs que contem o Topnave - Sidenave - Footer ?

Comment: Sim Pedro, pq se não o import sobrescreve a página atual, tem que importar só as divs.

Comment: Mas recrio a página  AdminPagina.aspx só com divs? ou deixo estar assim e importo so as divs ? Divido em 3 imports ? Topnave - Sidenave - Footer ?

Comment: Importar só as divs seria o ideal.

Comment: Ok vou tentar, muito obrigado pelo seu tempo . Quando tiver novidades digo

Comment: Dividindo os imports ficou a funcionar, agora é só tratar com css. Agora os scripts é que deixaram de funcionar, botao de logout e sessao. Quando importava a pagina completa funcionavam

Comment: Importa na atual.

Comment: Ja importei , o meu aspbutton por exemplo , reconhece que é um botão mas nao executa o script para fazer logout , e tambem me importa o nome da Sessao na Label , mas se eu a chamar a sessão noutro sitio qualquer diz que nao existe